# is Gnu compiler restrictions applicable to C language

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction, gnu

The Gnu C Compiler (gcc) allows labels as values as a language-extension:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html
But the documentation says:

if we use this mechanism to jump to code in a different function then totally
unpredictable things will happen.
what restrictions do we have for c like language?

Answer (score 1):

The restriction is not (only) in GCC, but in the C standard itself.

> A label name is the only kind of identifier that has function scope.
>   It can be used (in a goto statement) anywhere in the function in which
>   it appears, and is declared implicitly by its syntactic appearance
>   (followed by a : and a statement).

(from N1548, §6.2.1.3).

Having "label variables" doesn't change the fact that the environment in different functions (eg. stack) is completely different (and unlike inside of a single function, predicting what it would be is impossible); jumping around would break pretty much everything.

The stack problem more precisely: The values of the local function variables in the target function are unknown, the function parameters are unknown, as soon as the target functions ends it is unknown where the program should continue etc.etc. (And the stack is not the only problem)